# Structure for requirejs "page module"

Tags: javascript, asp.net, requirejs

In the current Asp.net WebForms based project we use requirejs to load js, modules on different pages. I just want to check if the following is a proper way to setup "modules" that connects to a specific page functionality.

For some specifc pages where more "unique" scripts is required we setup what we call a "Page Module". Since it's doesn't need to expose methods outside of its own scope we don't use define and instead just specify it like this:

```
require(['main'], function () {

    require(['jquery', 'app/Ajax', 'underscore'], function ($, ajax, _) {

        _.templateSettings = {
            interpolate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g,
            evaluate: /\{%([\s\S]+?)%\}/g,
            escape: /\{%-([\s\S]+?)%\}/g
        };

        var pageModule = function() {
            this.init();
        };

        pageModule.prototype.init = function () {
            var self = this;
            //init functionality
        };

        pageModule.prototype.method = function () {
            // function used by the pageModule itself
        }

        return new pageModule();
    });
});
```

Then in the bottom of the page html we call the require

```
<script>
    require(['pages/pageModule']);
</script>
```

Tried to look around for patterns like this to get a confirmation that this is a good way to utilize the functionality but haven't found much. Perhaps that's because this is not a good way to use it or that it's called something specific. Most examples uses the define but since the module should not be used by any other functions the define seems redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the official multipage example that looks a lot like what you have:

https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage

For example page1.js:

```
//Load common code that includes config, then load the app logic for this page.
requirejs(['./common'], function (common) {
    requirejs(['app/main1']);
});
```

And in page1.html:

```
<script data-main="js/page1" src="js/lib/require.js"></script>
```

(note: `requirejs` refers to the same function as `require`)

Comment: In their example the app/main2.js is defined as a AMD module (using define) so is that the recommended way or does my structure with defining the pageModule still correct?